# WooCommerce Product Not Being Added to Cart After Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

On my WooCommerce website, users can customize a product image on a canvas, then add the product to the cart. However, after implementing AJAX to upload the images and dynamically appending hidden input fields to the form with the image URLs, the product is not being added to the cart upon form submission. Below is the relevant code snippet and form HTML structure:

```js
// Capture the "Add to Cart" button click event
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.single_add_to_cart_button')) {
        console.log('Button clicked');  
        e.preventDefault();


                    // On successful image upload, submit the form to add the product to the cart
                    var cartForm = document.querySelector('.cart');
                    console.log('Cart form:', cartForm);
                    cartForm.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_image_url" value="http://google.com/image.png">`);
                    cartForm.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input type="hidden" name="preview_image_url" value="http://google.com/image2.png">`);                   
                    cartForm.submit();



    }
});
```

The AJAX call successfully uploads the images and the server responds with the URLs of the uploaded images. The hidden input fields are being added to the form with the correct URLs, as verified by inspecting the DOM and logging the form data to the console.

However, when I submit the form (using cartForm.submit();), the product is not being added to the cart. The form action URL is correct and points to the product page. I have also verified that the server-side script is set up to handle the form submission and add the item to the cart.

I have added console.log statements to trace the JavaScript execution and ensured that the cartForm.submit(); line is being reached. There are no errors in the browser console.

This is a clean wordpress install with just divi and my plugin installed. No styling or anything else, divi is just installed.

What could be causing the product not to be added to the cart, and how can I fix this issue? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What did you try?

I have created a custom WordPress theme where users can upload and position an image on a product. After customizing the image, users can click the "Add to Cart" button to upload their images via AJAX, append the image URLs as hidden input fields to the form, and then submit the form to add the product to the cart.

Here's a breakdown of my attempts:

I successfully set up the AJAX call to upload the images to the server.
I dynamically appended the image URLs to the form using insertAdjacentHTML.
I attempted to submit the form programmatically using cartForm.submit(); after the AJAX call is successful and the hidden input fields are added to the form.
What were you expecting?

I expected that after clicking the "Add to Cart" button, the images would be uploaded to the server, the image URLs would be appended to the form, and the form would be submitted to add the customized product to the cart. I expected to see the product added to the cart with the custom image URLs included in the order details.

What actually resulted?

The images are uploaded successfully, and the hidden input fields are correctly appended to the form with the right image URLs. However, the product is not being added to the cart upon form submission. The form appears to be submitted as the page reloads, but the cart remains empty. The server-side script seems to be working correctly as the AJAX call is successful, and no errors are reported in the browser console or server logs.

I have added extensive console logging to trace the JavaScript execution and ensured that the cartForm.submit(); line is being reached. Despite this, the product is not added to the cart, and I am at a loss for what might be going wrong.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this issue for a while.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean. I copied over the full code and not the Minimal Reproducible Example

Answer (score 1):

As jQuery is already enabled and loaded by WooCommerce, I use it.

In your script `preventDefault()` on add-to-cart ***submit*** button ***"click"*** event, disables WooCommerce Add to cart "submit", so when using form `submit()` event, it doesn't work.

In the revisited code below, I Remove/Change add to cart button properties, then I add a hidden custom add to cart submit button and I trigger "click" event on it:

```js
jQuery(function($){
    const cartForm = $('form.cart');

    $(document.body).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
        console.log('Button clicked');  
        e.preventDefault();


        // On successful image upload, submit the form to add the product to the cart
        cartForm.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_image_url" value="https://google.com/image.png">');
        cartForm.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="preview_image_url" value="https://google.com/image2.png">'); 
        // Remove/Change add to cart button properties
        $(this).removeAttr('name').prop('type', 'button'); 
        // Add a hidden add-to-cart submit button to the  form
        cartForm.append('<input type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="'+$(this).val()+'" style="display:none;">');
         // Click on hidden add to cart submit button            
        $('[name=add-to-cart]').trigger('click');


    });
});
```

Now the product is added to cart.

Below we include both images URLs as custom cart item data:

```php
// Add custom input fields values as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_input_fields_as_custom_cart_item_data' );
function add_custom_input_fields_as_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data ) {
    if( isset($_POST['uploaded_image_url']) ){
        $cart_item_data['uploaded_image_url'] = sanitize_url($_POST['uploaded_image_url']);
    }
    if( isset($_POST['preview_image_url']) ){
        $cart_item_data['preview_image_url'] = sanitize_url($_POST['preview_image_url']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

Tested and works.